# Delete Rows where there are multiple conditions on columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please use the below code for the dataframe.

Delete all Rows where ['Sachin', 'Virat'] scord more than 100 in the year '2014'

```
smd = [['Sachin', 1989, 130],
       ['Virat', 2014, 99],
       ['Sachin', 2014, 99],
       ['Virat', 2014, 183],
       ['Virat', 2014, 183],
       ['Rohit', 2014, 79],
       ['Virat', 2015, 129],
       ['Raina', 2014, 183],
       ['Rohit', 2014, 264],
       ['Sachin', 2014, 130],] 
df_smd = pd.DataFrame(smd, columns = ['Player', 'Year','Score'])
df_smd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write your conditions:

1. To get an equality, you can use `df.column_name == your_value`
2. To select rows which are in a list, [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) do the job.
3. To inverse the condition, use `~` operator.

Once you have the conditions, you can applied all them with `&` operator (and not `and`).

Here the code:

```
smd = [['Sachin', 1989, 130],
       ['Virat', 2014, 99],
       ['Sachin', 2014, 99],
       ['Virat', 2014, 183],
       ['Virat', 2014, 183],
       ['Rohit', 2014, 79],
       ['Virat', 2015, 129],
       ['Raina', 2014, 183],
       ['Rohit', 2014, 264],
       ['Sachin', 2014, 130]]
df_smd = pd.DataFrame(smd, columns=['Player', 'Year', 'Score'])

# Select row where player is 'Sachin' or 'Virat'
condition_name = df_smd.Player.isin(['Sachin', 'Virat'])
condition_score = df_smd.Score > 100
condition_year = df_smd.Year == 2014

# Apply all the conditions
output = df_smd[~(condition_name & condition_score & condition_year)]
print(output)
#    Player  Year  Score
# 0  Sachin  1989    130
# 1   Virat  2014     99
# 2  Sachin  2014     99
# 5   Rohit  2014     79
# 6   Virat  2015    129
# 7   Raina  2014    183
# 8   Rohit  2014    264
```

You can also do it with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) (even if I found it less natural..):

```
condition = (condition_name & condition_score & condition_year)
output = df_smd.drop(index=condition[condition].index)
print(output)
#    Player  Year  Score
# 0  Sachin  1989    130
# 1   Virat  2014     99
# 2  Sachin  2014     99
# 5   Rohit  2014     79
# 6   Virat  2015    129
# 7   Raina  2014    183
# 8   Rohit  2014    264
```

Comment: I want delete the output. Could you please help with the drop statement for this scenario

Comment: @anmolparida My fault, I updated the answer. Not sure `drop` is the easier way to do here.The update shows two ways.

Comment: @AlexandreB. Nice answer :). Didnt know you can do `condition[condition]` to get the values to drop.

Comment: @AlexandreB. That was great specially the ```condition[condition] ```